RSA Keys signature generation using SHA256 matching algorithm with php_openssl to verify signature
I am encountering difficulties with verifying a digital signature sent from my frontend application to my Laravel backend via an API request. According to the documentation, the process involves several steps:

Convert the parameters to a JSON string.
Hash the JSON string using the SHA256 algorithm.
Digitally sign the hashed value using the private key (not to be confused with the base64 private key).
Encode the obtained digital signature in base64 to derive the value of base64signature.

I've implemented the signature generation process in my frontend app using the following code snippet:
const generateSignature2 = (data: string, privateKeyPem: string): string =\> {
// Convert PEM-formatted private key to Forge RSA private key
const privateKey = forge.pki.privateKeyFromPem(privateKeyPem);
// Create SHA-256 hash of the data
const md = forge.md.sha256.create();
md.update(data, "raw");
const digest = md.digest();

// Sign the hash using RSA private key
const signature = privateKey.sign(md);
console.log("signature ", signature);
// Convert signature bytes to Base64
const signatureBase64 = forge.util.encode64(signature);

return signatureBase64;
}

and here is my backend function to verify the recieved signature
public static function VerifyDigitalSignature($data,$base_64_digital_signature,$public_key){
$isVerified = openssl_verify($data, base64_decode($base_64_digital_signature),$public_key);
return $isVerified;
}

Here is the function that is firts called in my backend to check rsa login
 public function validateRsaLogin(Request $request){
        $parameters=json_encode($request->post('Parameters'),JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
        $data=hash('SHA256',$parameters);
    
        $signature=RsaKeys::VerifyDigitalSignature($data,$request->header('base64signature'),base64_decode($request->header('base64publickey')));
        if($signature===1){
           return true;
        }elseif($signature===0){
          return false;
        }elseif($signature===-1||$signature===false){
         return -1;
        }

        return true;
    }

but this does not recognize the signature, any idea how can i fix this ? the docs says that i should be using SHA-256

. 2/ The Json string is then hased with sha256 algorithm.


The two codes use different digests, the node-forge code SHA-256 (explicit), the PHP code SHA-1 (by default). For compatibility, identical digests are required, e.g. SHA-256 in the PHP code. For this, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256 must be specified as the 4th parameter of openssl_verify().

Please check edited question, in the provided docs of my backend they say that i should be using SHA-256 to hash the data , i provided the function used to check rsa login

Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite PHP(?) forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

PHP/OpenSSL hashes automatically (in contrast to node-forge). Therefore, the non-hashed plaintext must be passed in PHP/OpenSSL. By default, SHA-1 is used as digest; for SHA-256, the digest must be specified explicitly (as described in my previous comment).

Thank you for your help, i update the code with OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256 but the verification of signature is still invalid

On my machine it works. But of course there may be other issues that are not obvious from your post, e.g. inconsistent keys, encoding/formatting problems (especially with regard to JSON) etc. If you can't solve the issue, you should post non-productive test data: associated key pair, message, signature and your most recent code so that a repro is possible.
